# Marionette.Object constructor

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm very newbie on Backbone + Marionette and I'm trying to inject an object into all initializers.

I'm doing this:

```
MyApp.on('before:start', function() { // Breakpoint 1

    Marionette.Object.extend({
        initialize: function(options) {
          // Breakpoint 2
        }
    }

});
```

Chrome's inspector stops at breakpoint 1 but not on 2.
It should stops at breakpoint 1 once and a several times at breakpoint 2, didn't?

Marionette's version: 2.4.7

Thank you for any advices.

Comment: What's the goal behind this? It looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I created a i18n file for each sub-app module. Each i18n file is independent and located inside module's folder. I'm using these approach to load the proper i18n file to apply on view. Any other ideas, I'm available =D.

Comment: It really depends how you load the i18n file, how you are using it and when you're using it. Are you using something like [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/)?

Comment: Also, that's not how `extend` works, it returns a new class. If you don't use the return value, it does nothing.

Comment: Actually I'm not using any i18n component. Just created an JSON object and inside views I'm calling like this: {{ from.json.object }}.
I tried to do this inside a view's initializer and it's worked but it's impossible (and not clever) to do the same to each initializer in project.
This approach I'm using was an advice.
I will checkout i18next. Thank you.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of how you're loading the `.json` file and how you're using it now, so we can try to improve it together.

Comment: Can't you simply create a base view that does this and extend every other views from it?

Comment: Actually I can BUT how much it will impact in my application? (I'm very newbie at Backbone and Marionette).

Comment: `extend` is function to create constructor, not create an instance. An instance is only created when you call `new Contructor()`, therefore everything is right in this case